# Select minimum value but higher than certain value

Tags: microsoft-excel, modeling

I want to select the minimum value in a table with 147 values, which is easy with the MIN-function in Excel. Now i want to select the minimum value which is bigger than 100%. 
I tried MINIFS, but it gives an error. 
=MINIFS(EN4:ET24;EN4:ET24;">"&100)

An addition to this question, i want it to solve it with an equation as it is supposed to work as a model in the end. 
Anyone knows how i can solve this problem?

Comment: what error are you getting?  And did you try: `=MINIFS(EN4:ET24;EN4:ET24;">100%")`

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked out!

Answer (score 0):

As you have it now it's checking if it's greater than 10000% because 1 is equal to 100% and you have >100

You can try @Scott Cramer's comment or try >1 instead.

Comment: Thank you! i figured it out now!